# Create Chocolatey Package and perform installation multiple times

Tags: chocolatey, choco

I want to use chocolatey to manage my windows application installer. However, my application requires multiple times installation with different parameters. I wonder is it possible to be achieved by just using one single choco package. If yes, how would the upgrade and uninstall perform? If no, it there any alternative solutions for these kind of tasks?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that although you are using the same installer (msi, exe, etc), you are actually installing different features of the installer.  Not sure why these aren't being installed all at the same time, but I guess that is down to your decisions.  In terms of how you can use Chocolatey for this, there would be nothing to stop you having multiple Chocolatey packages, each using the same underlying installer, but with a different set of parameters.  From there, you could create dependencies between the packages, so that installing a single package, actually installs everything that is required.